# Having issues with Drawable objects

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, drawable

I'm having a problem with this app that should be simple fix but I just can't figure out what the hell I'm doing wrong...All the app does is download an image in one thread and set the image in the other thread. I changed the ReadFile class to return a Drawable object into the variable finalImage then I have onPostExecute to set that image to the ImageView but...the only thing it is showing is an Android icon. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I'm guessing it has to do with the way I'm returning the Drawable from ReadFile class but I can't figure out what exactly.

```
package com.example.imageviewer;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final String URL_STRING = "http://cdn.theatlantic.com/static/infocus/putin091311/s_p15_0RTXUL0R.jpg";
    private final String FILENAME = "s_p15_0RTXUL0R.jpg";
    private ImageView fileImageView; 
    public Drawable finalImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fileImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fileImageView);

        new DownloadFile().execute();
        new ReadFile().execute();

    }

    class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // download and write the file
            try{
                // get the URL object
                URL url = new URL(URL_STRING);

                // get the input stream
                InputStream in = url.openStream();

                // get the output stream
                FileOutputStream out = 
                        openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                // read input and write output
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
                while (bytesRead != -1)
                {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
                }
                out.close();
                in.close();

                // return a message
                return "File downloaded";
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                return "Error: " + e.toString();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
            Log.d("Test", message);

            fileImageView.setImageDrawable(finalImage);

        }                
    }

        public class ReadFile extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Drawable>{

            @Override
            protected Drawable doInBackground(Void...params){
                try {
                    FileInputStream in = openFileInput(FILENAME);
                    Drawable image = Drawable.createFromStream(in, FILENAME);
                    fileImageView.setImageDrawable(image);
                    Log.d("Test", "File read");            
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Test", "Error: " + e.toString());
                }
                return finalImage;
            }

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
new DownloadFile().execute();
new ReadFile().execute();
```

As these are Asynchronous Tasks, they're running at the same time, and `ReadFile` is attempting to open your image file before `DownloadFile` has finished.

You merely need to move the `new ReadFile().execute();` to the `onPostExecute()` method of `DownloadFile`.

Then also add the following to `ReadFile`, to get the ImageView to refresh:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable nada) {
        fileImageView.invalidate();
    }
```

I tested to make sure that's all that was needed, and got a picture of Putin with a dog.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it doesn't appear to be working still. I'm just getting a white screen. So now my onPostExecute looks like this and it's inside the DownloadFile method. 

       <code> @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
         
         new ReadFile().execute();
          
            Log.d("Test", message);
           
            fileImageView.setImageDrawable(finalImage);

        }</code>

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention you need to call `invalidate()` on your ImageView. I've added the correction to the answer.

Comment: You can also get rid of the three lines that have `finalImage` in them; they're not doing anything.

Comment: Thanks man, that solved it. I would have never figured out that I needed to call invalidate() ...

Comment: No sweat! Glad to help.

Comment: I was running it on Android 4.4 kit kat and using the emulator that comes with ADT Eclipse...which is ungodly slow...

Answer (score 0):

You should return "image" instead of "finalImage" from the ReadFile task.

Also, you can try this instead of onPostExecute:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AsyncResponse {
    ...

    void processFinish(Drawable output) {
        fileImageView.setImageDrawable(finalImage);
    }
}
```

AsyncResponse.java:

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(Drawable output);
}
```

ReadFile.java:

```
        public class ReadFile extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Drawable>{

            @Override
            protected Drawable doInBackground(Void...params){
                Drawable image;
                try {
                    FileInputStream in = openFileInput(FILENAME);
                    image = Drawable.createFromStream(in, FILENAME);
                    Log.d("Test", "File read");            
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Test", "Error: " + e.toString());
                }
                return image;
            }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
        delegate.processFinish(result);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried to return just image but it just says variable isn't set even though I set it in the method...